# std::result_of applied to const overloaded methods

Tags: c++, static, constants, typedef, decltype

If I give

```
typedef std::vector<int> v;
```

Then the below can be used to capture the type of the constant iterator (an alternative is to use `v::const_iterator`, but this depends on the `const_iterator` member type being explicitly defined in the class.

```
typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(&v::cbegin)(v*)>::type const_iterator;
```

Indeed, we can check that the above does as we want.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<const_iterator, typename v::const_iterator>::value);
```

However, I find a compiler failure on the below.

```
typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(&v::begin)(v*)>::type iterator;
```

The compiler complains that the method is overloaded (by const modifier) and cannot be unambiguously resolved.  However, I cannot find out the syntax to resolve the ambiguity.  At a minimum, one expects the below to be unambiguous, because only the const version can operate on a const object.  However, even the below is similarly problematic.

```
typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(&v::begin)(const v*)>::type const_iterator2;
```

How do I refer to a particular const or nonconst version of begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
using v = std::vector<int>;
using iter = decltype(std::declval<v>().begin());
static_assert(std::is_same<iter, typename v::iterator>::value);
```

The issue here is that `&v::begin` is ambiguous.  There are two `v::begin` functions, and the `&` operator has no way to know which one to return the address of.  Using `std::declval` gets around that.  Since the return type of `std::declval<v>()` is `v`, the compiler knows you're interested in the non-const `v::begin()`.

Similarly, the following gets you the const version:

```
using citer = decltype(std::declval<const v>().begin());
static_assert(std::is_same<citer, typename v::contst_iterator>::value);
```

Note that no objects are created in this code.  `std::declval` has no definition, so it only works in unevaluated contexts like `decltype`.

Comment: I understad this response, but why doesn't the `const` modifier of the `v*` argument above resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: Return type of `std::declval<v>()` isn't `v`.

Comment: @epl because `&` has already tried and failed to take the address of an ambiguous function name before the parameters are ever looked at.

Comment: @skypjack yes, it's technically `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`, so `v&&` for non-const and `const v&` for const, but I didn't feel that detail was really relevant.